# Upload files Using AJAX & CodeIgniter 3.0.1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Please be nice..

It's been two days that I'm struggling with this, So I decided to post it.

**What I have :**

A fresh CodeIgniter installation on my localhost (Windows), with one controller and one view. Everything is working perfectly.

**What I want to do :**

Upload an image using AJAX with CodeIgniter without reloading the page.

**My controller (Test.php) :**

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {
   public function index()
   {
        # Started working with file upload.
        $validFiles = array(
            'upload_path'   => './assets',
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|gif',
            'max_size'      => 250000
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $validFiles);
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('newsphoto'))
        {
            echo "Image Uploaded Successfully!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }

   }

   public function upload()
   {
      $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->view('test');
   }
}
```

**My View (test.php) :**

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="CustomForm">
    <?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url().'test', array('class' => 'newsForm')); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="file" class="InputField" name="newsphoto" value="">
        <input type="text" class="InputField" name="title" value="">
        <textarea name="news" class="InputField" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <button>Go</button>
    </div>
    <?php form_close(); ?>
</div> 
</body>
<html>
```

**My JS script (It's in the view I separated it to make it easy to read) :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
               var form = $('form.newsForm');
               form.on('submit', function (c) {
                   c.preventDefault();

                   var data = new FormData();
                   $.each($('form.newsForm :input'), function(i, fileds){
                       data.append($(fileds).attr('name'), $(fileds).val());
                   });
                   $.each($('form.newsForm input[type=file]')[0].files, function (i, file) {
                       data.append(file.name, file);
                   });
                   $.ajax({
                       url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/test',
                       data: data,
                       cache: false,
                       contentType: false,
                       processData: false,
                       type: 'POST',
                       success: function (c) {
                           var msg = $('div.jsMessage');
                           msg.empty();
                           msg.html(c);
                       }
                   });
                   return false;
               });
           })
</script>
```

**What I'm getting now :**

I'm getting a simple upload that works correctly, as the picture shows.
[image: Upload result]

I think that my ajax code doesn't run, and I'm not sure it'll work if it does. Any help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can simply populate your form data with `new FormData($('form.newsForm')[0])`. So you don't need, any `each` statements`... But what do you mean your ajax code doesn't run? Are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. It doeasn't run because I can't make it run. When I click on "go" it just submits the form normally (reloading page).

Comment: And there is no error in your console? Cause if the js code is broken, then it will be posted as normaly.

Comment: No there is no errors.. It shouldn't do so right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Ajax File Uploader : [github](http://goo.gl/txUB3t)

Below you can find a working example for your scenario.

**routes.php**

```
$route['form'] = 'Test/upload';
$route['upload'] = 'Test';
```

**config.php**

> The code mentioned helps maintaining the configuration of base url as such for both localhost and the live server. You don't have to update the `$config['base_url']`, when you move the files to live server. You can find that piece of code below.

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$root";
```

**autoload.php**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

**controller**  -   Test.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Test extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            # Started working with file upload.
            $validFiles = array(
                'upload_path'   => 'assets',
                'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|gif',
                'max_size'      => 250000
            );
            $this->load->library('upload', $validFiles);
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('newsphoto'))
            {
                $return['msg']='Image Uploaded Successfully!';
                echo json_encode($return);


            }
            else
            {
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            }

        }

        public function upload()
        {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->view('test');
        }
   }
```

**View :**  test.php

> Have you used jquery library in your view ? using that would make the JS work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/JS/ajaxfileupload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="CustomForm">
    <?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url().'index.php/upload', array('class' => 'newsForm')); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="file" id="newsphoto" class="InputField" name="newsphoto" value="">
        <input type="text" id="title" class="InputField" name="title" value="">
        <textarea name="news" id="news" class="InputField" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <button> Upload</button>
    </div>
    <?php form_close(); ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var form = $('form.newsForm');
        form.on('submit', function (c) {
            c.preventDefault();

            var data = new FormData();
            $.each($('form.newsForm :input'), function(i, fileds){
                data.append($(fileds).attr('name'), $(fileds).val());
            });
            $.each($('form.newsForm input[type=file]')[0].files, function (i, file) {
                data.append(file.name, file);
            });

            var param = {'title':$('#title').val(),'news':$('#news').val()};

            $.ajaxFileUpload
            (

                {
                    url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/upload',
                    secureuri:false,
                    data: param,
                    fileElementId:'newsphoto',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        console.log("I'm sending AJAX.");
                        //display loading?
                    },
                    success: function (data, status)
                    {
                        alert(data.msg);
                    },
                    error: function (data, status, e)
                    {
                        alert(e);
                    }
                }
            );
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: You can also try drop zone which is a much better alternative .http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after a few minutes this works perfectly! Thanks again!